# Just insert "Hour:Minutes" of a Date in BDD (Hibernate)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, pojo

I want to insert values in my table and I have to format some dates before that.

I don't know if I need to do this in my POJO or with Hibernate.

Maybe annotations exist to specify format in POJO ?

(Sorry for my mistakes and language, I recently speak English)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the @Temporal annotation.

For time it should be

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate your `java.lang.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` field with `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` annotation.

Comment: The problem isn't resolved...

I see in my database : 01/01/1970 10:00:00

Does it change something to use a java.util.Date instead of java.lang.Date ?